# strange switch in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have some question about the following switch in Linux Kernel, somebody can explain please the last `case`, why do I need this case at all, if it is empty? thanks in advance

```
switch (prev->state) {
    case TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE:
        if (unlikely(signal_pending(prev))) {
            prev->state = TASK_RUNNING;
            break;
        }
    default:
        deactivate_task(prev, rq);
    case TASK_RUNNING:
        ;
    }
```

#### EDITED

I took it from linux 2.4.18, which I'm currently learning, there is no comment there about, why this way

Comment: I would be extremely interested to know the answer. I suspect it's performance related, but who knows?

Comment: My guess would be that this is for documentation, to show that `TASK_RUNNING` was not simply forgotten.

Comment: @Oded though a comment might have been better.

Comment: Did this code go out of the Linux kernel a long time ago? http://lkml.org/lkml/2003/12/20/73

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `prev->state == TASK_RUNNING` and you don't have the last case, then `deactivate_task` will be called, which is presumably not desired here. This is just a quick way of doing something special for `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` and something different for every other state but `TASK_RUNNING`.

Answer (score 1):

Following is what they do there:

```
If prev->state == TASK_RUNNING -> do nothing.
If prev->state == TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE - > signal_pending() and then possibly deactivate_task()
In any other case just deactivate_task().
```